# c#: reading html source of a webpage into a string

Tags: c#

I would like to be able to read the html source of a certain webpage into a string in c# using winforms

how do I do this?

Comment: framework version? proxy requirements?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
string html = new WebClient().DownloadString("http://twitter.com");
```

And now with async/await hotness in C# 5

```
string html = await new WebClient().DownloadStringTaskAsync("http://github.com");
```

Comment: I get Error "; expected" on that second line. I use VS2012 but it seems that await doesn't work. If I try  string html = await wc.DownloadStringTaskAsync("link"); I get: "Error 1 The 'await' operator can only be used within an async method..." Do I need to add some reference to the project?

Comment: I don't intend this response to sound like snark, although I understand it may come across that way; but the error message says exactly what the resolution is :) the method that contains that line has to be decorated with the "async" keyword.

Answer (score 10):

Have a look at [WebClient.DownloadString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fhd1f0sw(v=VS.80).aspx):

```
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
    string html = wc.DownloadString(address);
}
```

You can use [WebClient.DownloadStringAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms144202(v=VS.80).aspx) or a [BackgroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) to download the file without blocking the UI.

Comment: Webclient is an IDisposable, so don't forget the `using` block.

Comment: joel can u explain that comment to me please

Comment: @every_answer_gets_a_point: Joel Coehoorn is referring to the `using` block which is present in my answer, but not in the answer of Joel Martinez. Since WebClient implements the IDisposable interface, the `using` block should be present.

Answer (score 3):

```
var req = WebRequest.Create("http://www.dannythorpe.com");
req.BeginGetResponse(r =>
{
    var response = req.EndGetResponse(r);
    var stream = response.GetResponseStream();
    var reader = new StreamReader(stream, true);
    var str = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.WriteLine(str);
}, null);
```

Comment: thank you, but why dont you think joel's response is good?

Comment: I have no opinion of Joel's solution.  Never heard of WebClient.DownloadString before this post.  This is the code I use.  WebClient.DownloadString looks simpler to use, but may not provide the same level of control (error handling, etc) as doing the separate steps yourself.  (Joel and I composed and posted simultaneously)