# Ä is shown in string as <?>

Tags: c#

I get the html-content and show it in a TextBox, but the "ä" is a `<?>`.
It's like Windows doesn't get the ä...

I get the Htmlcontent like this:

```
public async Task<string> MakeWebRequest()
{
    HttpClient http = new HttpClient();
    HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("***URL***");
    return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
}
```

How can I get a match in regex to the ä, which Looks like an "?" ?

Comment: check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22649473/getting-an-utf-8-response-with-httpclient-in-windows-store-apps

Comment: Did you try using your own `StreamReader` on `ReadAsStreamAsync` and setting the encoding of that reader explicitly, eg to UTF8? I once had a similar problem and was able to resolve it this way?

Comment: there are several other ways to read html as string take a look on them .
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2625618/c-reading-html-source-of-a-webpage-into-a-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something in the lines of:

```
using (var client = Connector.GetHttpClient())
{
    var response = await client.GetByteArrayAsync(url);
    data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response);
}
```

Comment: @DieterMüller You can use "return await  Encoding.UTF8.GetString(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());", other was just to hint that code could be written better.

Comment: The "(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync())" don't work