# How to read html file opened in safari using openURL()

Tags: c#, html, ios, xamarin

I am trying to open a page using

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(url)
```

I do few clicks and then it opens another page. I want to read that html body/content of newly opened page. How do I go about it?

Is there any other way to open a browser (in built browser and not UIWebview) and do the same?

Edit :
Say, I am opening google

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication.openURL(new NSUrl("www.google.com"));
```

I search for apple and it shows the results. Now I click wikipedia and it opens a page ie., wikipedia page for apple.
How do i get the html content of that wikipedia apple page? is there a way?

Comment: You need to be more precise with your question. We have no idea where to start answering because we don't know exactly what your problem is. could you paste more code to give us some context?

Comment: @JonathanYanivBenAvraham I have edited. i hope it is clear now

Comment: Well you could always right click and view source, that'll give you the HTML layout of the webpage

Comment: Is there a way to read that in your app ? @JonathanYanivBenAvraham

Comment: [this is a potential solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2625638/5971639)

Comment: this is a good solution if i know link address the user clicks, but I dont know that @JonathanYanivBenAvraham

Comment: create an eventHandler and store the link the user clicks in a string variable? and use the variable instead a string in the parentheses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In iOS you won't be able to do that.

I could do this easily using a `WebView` inside a `ViewController`.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    webView.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl("https://xamarin.com")));

    webView.LoadFinished += (sender, e) =>
    {
        if (webView.IsLoading)
        {
            return;
        }
        var html = webView.EvaluateJavascript("document.documentElement.outerHTML");
    };
}
```

Comment: Thank you !! Can you tell me how to synchronise the loadfinished. For example, i have to return the html variable. It returns a null right now. How to wait for the loading to finish before returning it.?

Comment: When you call the EvaluateJavascript the page has already loaded totally. You will get the full HTML. You don't need to synchronize.